# Minecraft prefix

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

In my Minecraft server, I have prefixes set up for groups but when I join The Nether or The End the prefixes go away and it's permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In permissions plugins, each world is handled separately, as to, for example, make a world where players and freely mine for materials, and another is strictly build only. To keep the exact permissions all that needs to be done is copy and paste all the Overworld permissions into the Nether and End permissions, and to know exactly what it would look like, I would have to know what permissions plugin you're using. However, I believe those two worlds are in there by default.